# Displaying GIF image from URL retrived as JSON array response

Tags: json, angular

I am getting JSON array as response from external API which contains list of GIFs. Now I have the GIF URLs as part of this response which I want to show as images on Angular front end html page.

I tried iterating over the response using  but that doesn't seem to work.

JSON response

```
0: {…}
​​​
analytics: Object { onload: {…}, onclick: {…}, onsent: {…} }
​​​
bitly_gif_url: "https://gph.is/YC1q17"
​​​
bitly_url: "https://gph.is/YC1q17"
​​​
content_url: ""
​​​
embed_url: "https://giphy.com/embed/6XeQfKBcO3K6c"
​​​
id: "6XeQfKBcO3K6c"
​​​
images: Object { fixed_height_still: {…}, original_still: {…}, fixed_width: {…}, … }
​​​
import_datetime: "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
​​​
is_sticker: 0
​​​
rating: "g"
​​​
slug: "hello-waving-movie-6XeQfKBcO3K6c"

source: ""
​​​
source_post_url: ""
​​​
source_tld: ""
​​​
title: "ryan gosling hello GIF"
​​​
trending_datetime: "2017-02-27 21:45:01"
​​​
type: "gif"
​​​
url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/hello-waving-movie-6XeQfKBcO3K6c"
​​​
username: ""
```

I just want the list of images (say 20) coming as response to be shown in row column mode in UI.

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON....also the way you doing to display in angular

Comment: I am not sure exactly how to display the Gif image from these URLs in Angular.
 
The response JSON contains 25 objects with similar data as one shown above,

    {…}
​
    data: Array(25) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​
    meta: Object { status: 200, msg: "OK", response_id:        "5ced4162624a457149c6dcda" }
​
    pagination: Object { total_count: 2447, count: 25, offset: 0 }
​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
    dashboard.component.ts:26:14

Comment: just use some `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject))` and see the output in browser console

Comment: You want to see the response JSON?

{"data":[{"type":"gif","id":"6XeQfKBcO3K6c","slug":"hello-waving-movie-6XeQfKBcO3K6c","url":"https://giphy.com/gifs/hello-waving-movie-6XeQfKBcO3K6c","bitly_gif_url":"https://gph.is/YC1q17","bitly_url":"https://gph.is/YC1q17","embed_url":"https://giphy.com/embed/6XeQfKBcO3K6c","username":"","source":"","rating":"g","content_url":"","source_tld":"","source_post_url":"","is_sticker":0,"import_datetime":"1970-01-01

Comment: Yes.....also the code snippet which you are trying to display using angular

Comment: I got it now. Thanks. 

This is the code I am using for now

<div class="gifs-container">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of data">
      <img src={{item.images.original.url}}>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194057/discussion-between-nidhish-krishnan-and-sourav-mehra).

Answer (score 0):

I got the actual GIF image URL by getting the complete JSON response details.

To display it simply calling the complete URL for the image,

```
<div class="gifs-card-container"  *ngFor="let item of data">
  <img src={{item.images.original.url}}>
</div>
```